# JOptionPane degrades application performance?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am checking the below condion and displaying dialog box

```
if(query.contains(tab))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Owner does not have privileges to access given table");
        }
```

I want when the dialog box is displayed and condition is true .further execution should stop there itself.How to do this?

and Does JOptionPane degrades application performance? because my application takes lot of time to display dialog box.

Edit:

```
  for(int i=0; i<ia.length; i++) 
      {

                tab=  ia[i].toString(); 
                    if(query.contains(tab))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Owner does not have privileges to access given table");
                    break;
                }
        }
//rest code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you comments on @Robin's answer:

> It stops untill the user disposes dialog but I want to stop the
> further execution even after the dialog box is closed i.e I want to
> stop execution of task which are there after above if block.
>
> ---
>
> Please see edited post.I want to block rest code part,how can I add
> it in else?

What you can do in your case is: take a flag to decide whether to execute rest of code or not. Some thing like:

```
boolean executeCode = true; // boolean flag to decide
for(int i=0; i<ia.length; i++)  {
   tab=  ia[i].toString(); 
   if(query.contains(tab)) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   "Owner does not have privileges to access given table");
      executeCode= false; // do not want to execute the rest of code
      break;
   }
}
if (executeCode) {
   //rest code
}
```

<sub>I'm not completely sure that I have understood your problem well, but I posted this answer based on what I understood from your above comments and it might also become hard to explain this in comments. Notify me if I'm wrong or have not understood it properly.</sub>

Comment: That is working thanks.but I have another problem now.Control comes inside if block but not able to show JOptionPane.Progress bar keeps rotating.Thats why I said before it degrades app performance.Any suggestions?

Comment: I meant the progress bar of Internet explorer.I am not sure it is called progress bar but it shows status of page.

Comment: Oh.. so you are making an applet that is shown in browser, right?

Comment: It is jsp page and above code is in action class using struts framework.

Comment: @happy I don't think you can use JOptionPane and other swing stuffs in struts. `J2SE != J2EE`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: How can I display message box in struts?

Comment: @happy I'm not good in struts, you should another question regarding this so experts can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the class javadoc of the `JOptionPane` class:

> All dialogs are modal. Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete.

So further execution will stop there automatically until the user disposes of the dialog.

And I never encountered any performance issues showing a `JOptionPane`. How did you determine it degrades your performance ?

Comment: It stops untill the user disposes dialog but I want to stop the further execution even after the dialog box is closed i.e I want to stop execution of task which are there after above if block.

Comment: @happy if you doesn't want to execute anything except that `if` block then write everything else in `else` block.

Comment: @Harry Please see edited post.I want to block rest code part,how can I add it in else?